# Magento - disable indexer for specific store

Tags: magento, indexing

I'm using 5 stores only for orders (no frontend, only backend).

Is there a way to disable indexer process (especially catalog_product_flat and catalog_search) for specific store id?

Comment: Why do you want this functionality, can you provide more details?

Comment: Reindexing of these data take a long time (~1 hour), I'm getting many "General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" when users use search form. I'm getting also some order fail. If I disable indexer for 5 of our 9 stores...

Comment: are you reindexing from Magento admin panel?

Comment: no, only from "php shell/indexer.php" and "getModel('index/indexer')->reindex"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't disable it in configuration. it's easy to do for the flat index, you have to update a loop where it creates

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat::_processEvent
```

The next step is:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer
```

The next step is:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer
```

Now one of the main functions (this function calls rebuild function and fill data into the table):

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::reindexAll
```

And your final call:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::rebuild
```

There is a loop in the function:

```
public function rebuild($store = null)
{
    if ($store === null) {
        foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
            $this->rebuild($store->getId());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

if you update this loop, you can skip the desired store from flat indexer. Location of the function is:
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php:121`

And very similar logic for a FullText search index:
`\Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::rebuildIndex`